# How to call method to plot Graph Android

Tags: android, graph

I've been trying to plot a graph from two ArrayLists on my Android Application. I got the values from ArrayList succeed, but I can't call method to get values.

I create this method which gets values from my database:

```
public DataPoint[] setData(String data)
{
    TextView editText4;
    editText4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    String[] lucas = data.split(",");

    List<String> ok = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(lucas));
    List<String> yes = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(lucas));

    int n = ok.size();     //to find out the no. of data-points
    editText4.setText(String.valueOf(n));
    DataPoint[] values = new DataPoint[n];     //creating an object of type DataPoint[] of size 'n'
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
        DataPoint v = new DataPoint(Double.parseDouble(ok.get(i)), Double.parseDouble(yes.get(i)));
        values[i] = v;
     }
     return values;
 }
```

My problem is here in setData (Cannot Resolve symbol 'setData') :

```
GraphView graph;
PointsGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;       //an Object of the PointsGraphSeries for plotting scatter graphs
graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
series = new PointsGraphSeries<>(setData);   //initializing/defining series to get the data from the method 'data()'
graph.addSeries(series);                   //adding the series to the GraphView
series.setShape(PointsGraphSeries.Shape.POINT);
series.setSize(6);
```

Answer (score 0):

As looking for your code looks that you have method setData(String data) but in `series = new PointsGraphSeries<>(setData);` you are calling variable. Please assing result from setData(String data) method to local variable and then use it in mentioned line of code.

Comment: Thanks for aswering me!! I am sorry, Robert but I am a newbie.... How could I do this?

Comment: try with DataPoint[] dataPoints = setData(""); and then series = new PointsGraphSeries<>(dataPoints);

Comment: DataPoint[] dataPoints = setData("");

            GraphView graph;
            PointsGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;       //an Object of the PointsGraphSeries for plotting scatter graphs
            graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);

            series = new PointsGraphSeries<>(dataPoints);   //initializing/defining series to get the data from the method 'data()'
            graph.addSeries(series);                   //adding the series to the GraphView
            series.setShape(PointsGraphSeries.Shape.POINT);
            series.setSize(6);

Comment: I don't know if this scripts works:  DataPoint[] values = new DataPoint[n];     //creating an object of type DataPoint[] of size 'n'
             for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                 DataPoint v = new DataPoint(Double.parseDouble(ok.get(i)), Double.parseDouble(yes.get(i)));
                 values[i] = v;

               Double a = Double.parseDouble(ok.get(i));
                 editText4.setText(String.valueOf(a));

Comment: Does somebody help me?

Comment: Yo have to replace "" in setData() to your String object - some source data